# Looking for finite rings with certain properties...

Tags: ring-theory

1. One example I need is of a finite associative ring A with non-transitive ideals (that is, there exists some I an ideal of A, and J an ideal of I, such that J is not an ideal of A).  Also, if we call ideals of ideals of A 'accessible subrings of A', then some accessible subring of A has a homomorphic image K such that K is ***not*** an accessible subring of a homomorphic image of A.
2. Another example I'm searching for is a finite *non-associative* ring with two or more nonzero *simple* accessible subrings (that is, the only ideals of these accessible subrings are themselves and 0).
3. A third example I'm searching for is a finite non-associative ring A such that all homomorphic images of accessible subrings of A are accessible subrings of homomorphic images of A.  I would also be happy to find one where only the *simple* homomorphic images of accessible subrings of A are accessible subrings of homomorphic images of A.

I realise these are very specific but I have searched high and low and so my only option is to hope somebody somewhere has found at least one of these creatures... or can point me in a possible direction to find them.  Thanks.

Comment: So to make sure we're all on the same page, the second two examples must not be associative (the "non" in nonassociative could be interpreted as it is for commutative rings: "not necessarily - ") And secondly, "simple accessible" is apparently necessarily a simple ring, so it's a subclass of the class of simple rings?

Comment: Yes that's right - that second two must be strictly 'non'-associative, and the simple accessible of A will be a simple subring of A, not necessarily an ideal (but it will be an ideal of an ideal of an ideal etc.. of A - i.e. part of a chain of ideals).